# RGB To HSV in Python using colorsys

Tags: python, python-3.x, rgb, colorsys

To covert RGB To HSV, I used this code:

```
import colorsys
def RGB_To_HSV(Red: int, Green: int, Blue: int):
    for I in colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(Red / 255, Green / 255, Blue / 255):
        H, S, V = round(360*I[0]), round(100*I[1]), round(100*I[2])
    return (H, S, V)

print(RGB_To_HSV(255,127,0))
```

But I get an error saying that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\GHJ.py", line 17, in <module>
        print(RGB_To_HSV(255,127,0))
    File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\GHJ.py", line 14, in RGB_To_HSV
        H, S, V = round(360*I[0]), round(100*I[1]), round(100*I[2])
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where the code says `for I in colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(Red / 255, Green / 255, Blue / 255):`, what do you think this means? In particular, what do you expect will be the value of ``I` each time through the loop? Where the code says `H, S, V = round(360*I[0]), round(100*I[1]), round(100*I[2])`, how many times do you think this line of code should run, in order to compute the desired result? Why? According to the code logic that is written, how many times will it run? Why? What exactly do you expect as the result of `colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(Red / 255, Green / 255, Blue / 255)`? Did you **check that**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import colorsys
print(colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(255 / 255, 127 / 255, 0 / 255))

#output
(0.08300653594771241, 1.0, 1.0)
```

---

If you do a `forloop` you will get individual float values:

```
for I in colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(255 / 255, 127 / 255, 0 / 255):
    print(I)

#output
0.08300653594771241
1.0
1.0
```

---

**You need to remove your `forloop`**

```
import colorsys
def RGB_To_HSV(Red: int, Green: int, Blue: int):
    I = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(Red / 255, Green / 255, Blue / 255)
    H, S, V = round(360*I[0]), round(100*I[1]), round(100*I[2])
    return (H, S, V)
```

---

```
print(RGB_To_HSV(255,127,0))

#output
(30, 100, 100)
```